# Kendo UI treelist and angular - how to determine if it's fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

In my HTML, I have:

```
<kendo-treelist 
   k-auto-bind="true" 
   k-data-source="dataSourceAssignment" 
   k-columns="Assignmentcols"
   k-rebind="Assignmentcols">
</kendo-treelist>
```

In the JS file, I am connecting it to the data source by:

```
$scope.dataSourceAssignment = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
  transport: {
     read: function (options) {
         //code here
     },
     schema: {
         model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {
               //fields here
            },
            expanded: true
         }
     }
});
```

Is there any way I could determine if the tree has fully loaded (i.e. 'no more hourglass spinning')?

I want to call a function to stop the 'loading....' UI then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be an `onDataBound` event. Try adding that as an attribute of the tag.

```
<kendo-treelist 
   k-auto-bind="true" 
   k-data-source="dataSourceAssignment" 
   k-data-bound="dataBoundHandler" 
   k-columns="Assignmentcols"
   k-rebind="Assignmentcols">
</kendo-treelist>
```

See: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/events

Comment: This works. I had to set a condition though so the dataBound handler only triggers when I load my tree and not when page initially loads.